# How to change corporate wellness policy to be vendor-neutral and objective?

Tags: company-culture, company-policy, health

My company offers a wellness incentive for employees if we do 10 weeks of Weight Watchers. But this requires employees to buy a single brand of weight loss, and alienates other who don't wish to buy it. I feel that running our wellness program this way not only discriminates against employees who achieve good health through other approaches but also limits the ideas available to employees by accepting only one. Furthermore, simply buying a weight-loss product for 10 weeks is not an indicator of good health. How do I persuade my company to reward employees for good health based on vendor-neutral, objective measurements such as body fat percentage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Companies often get a commission for the products they can sell to their employees. It could just be that they're giving back that commission to those employees buying the stuff in the first place through that wellness incentive. In other words, do not assume ill-intent on their part. Just assume that they came up with the first ready-made option that presented itself to them and that they didn't take the time to investigate anything else.

If you want other options to be considered, you'll have to hunt them down yourself, and make sure that they're already pre-packaged for the company to use. For instance, if you can partner with a gym near your employer, that's all the better. Just don't make it too complicated. Unless you want this initiative to become your new part-time job to manage (instead of your current job), pick an existing program that such a gym already offers that your company might be able to piggy-back on and adapt.

Whatever you do, do not just complain without being willing to work on the issue yourself. Most likely, health and fitness are not parts of the core competency of your employer, and your employer just relies on enthusiastic volunteers within its own ranks to champion health-related initiatives.

Comment: what I'd like to propose is a results-oriented wellness program based on objective measurements such as body fat percentage and [biomarkers](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19264094). This seems less complicated than getting employees to follow program or diet.

Comment: You sold me on the idea already. It's a good one. My only problem is that someone needs to measure that body fat percentage. Are you going to do it? Who is? How much are they going to get paid? What else will you include in your program? Who are you going to partner with?